# Problems with endpoint host name containing emoji

Tags: hostname, endpoint

Recently while testing my application I stumbled upon the possibility to change the computer name of a windows device (probably also possible with unix and any other OS but did not test with that) to contain an emoji ().

Now I started to wonder if I would run into trouble if I would configure a host name of an endpoint in my AD to contain an emoji.

I know its probably bad practice to use such characters in the host name, but I was wondering if it was reasonable to expect such host names (e.g. if I would be implementing some sort of endpoint library).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.  But in today’s world, I’d say yes, you need to be able to deal with not just emojis, but any sort of character covered by Unicode.